# Laravel 5 Connection Code Meaning

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I have used below line of Code and its working fine i know that `getDatabaseName()` is a member function of Connection class but i want to know what is the meaning of `DB::connection()` whether it is used for creating object of connection class or some thing else ?

```
DB::connection()->getDatabaseName(); //  Meaning of this Line
 getDatabaseName()  //  function of connection class [Clear to Me]
DB::connection() // it is confusing what does it mean
```

Answer (score 4):

`DB` is a Laravel [*Facade*](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/facades). The basically work this way:

1. Static call to the Facade class (`DB::connection()`)
2. The Facade class catches that static call with `__callStatic`
3. It gets an actual instance of the underlying class (`DatabaseManager`)
4. The original call gets forwarded as a non-static call to the instance (`$db->connection()`)

#### Let's look at some source code

`Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade`

```
public static function __callStatic($method, $args)
{
    $instance = static::getFacadeRoot();

    // method content simplified for brevity
    return call_user_func_array(array($instance, $method), $args);
}
```

`getFacadeRoot()` essentially returns the actual instance. Either from the global [Application IoC Container](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/ioc) or from a variable in the facade itself (if you use it the second time)

Then `call_user_func_array` is used to call the original method `$method` on the instance.

---

If you want to know what facade resolves to which class you can use [this reference](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/facades#facade-class-reference) or go to the Facade class in the source and search for a `@see` in the docblock of the class:

```
/**
 * @see \Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager
 * @see \Illuminate\Database\Connection
 */
class DB extends Facade {
```